# GDAL: can I rasterize a layer's FIDs without having an explicit field id column?

Tags: gdal, rasterization

I would like to rasterize a layer by FID without adding an FID field to the layer.  Is this possible with GDAL?  Something like like this:

```
raster = gdal.Open(raster_path, gdal.GA_Update)
vector = ogr.Open(vector_path)
layer = vector.GetLayer()
gdal.RasterizeLayer(
    raster, [1], layer, options=["ATTRIBUTE=FID"])
```

But of course this doesn't work because `FID` is not defined.  I've tried using `layer.GetFIDColumn()` but I get an empty string back.  That's not surprising since this is the result if  `GetFIDColumn` is not supported.

Otherwise, my approach is to create a new DataSource with an FID field only.  Copy the original's layer geometry to this one while updating the FID value.  Rasterize that layer, then delete it.  I'd like to avoid this solution since in general I don't have control over the size of geometries coming in.  It seems wasteful to create a whole copy to add an FID field.  And dangerous to add a field to the original input only to delete it later.

Comment: If it's a shapefile the FID field doesn't truly exist and I would consider it dangerous to use. FID values in a shapefile are fluid and can change; on every save the values are compressed to 0 based, contiguous, unique and ascending.. it would be much better to use a static field - even if you start by copying the FID to a new field.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelMiles-Stimson, that's the info I need.  Do you want to post this as an answer so I can mark it answered?

Comment: @Rich Did you figure out how to do this without FID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FID field of a shapefile does't truly exist, if you were to open the .DBF file in Microsoft Excel (or similar) you would find that the FID column is not there.. this is because the ID of the row is managed by the database and is *always* compressed to 0 based, contiguous (no gaps), ascending and unique. When a shapefile is edited the modified rows are moved to the end then compressed again on save.

For this reason it is not good to trust the FID values of a shapefile. It is much better to use a static field which can be generated by calculating (copying) the row number initially but will remain unmodified, this field would then be available to rasterize by.

## Edit

Justin Liang asked for a way to calculate the FID to a new field, here is a quick script to do just that:

```
import sys
from osgeo import ogr

daShapefile = sys.argv[1] # input shapefile, field ID must already exist
driver      = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
dataSource  = driver.Open(daShapefile, 1) # 1 for writable
layer       = dataSource.GetLayer()       # get the layer for this datasource

for Ft in layer:
    ThisID = int(Ft.GetFID())
    print('ID is {}'.format(ThisID))
    Ft.SetField('ID',ThisID)          # Write the FID to the ID field
    layer.SetFeature(Ft)              # update the feature
dataSource = None                     # Save and close the datasource
```

Comment: Do you know of an example in python where the row number is copied to a static field?

Comment: @JustinLiang there are two ways to do this that spring to mind immediately, via QGIS https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html calculate to $id using the QGIS field calculator. I have added a quick script to calculate a field value based on the FID of the row, I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This works for GPKG format (which is based on SQLite3):

```
gdal_rasterize -a id -sql "select row_number() over (order by random()) as id, geom from layer_name" -ot UInt32 -tr 10 10 geoset.gpkg geoset.tif
```